# Load title from database based on member country

Tags: php, mysqli, join

As tim suggested, some changes to the database was necessary. I have posed an improved version of this question at [Get title from database based on member country](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129022/get-title-from-database-based-on-member-country).

---

I have the following database:

[image: Database sample information]

Each member may have multiple countries (1:n) mapped in table `country2memb`. It's even possible that one member gets the same country multiple times (for example, Bernd got US twice).

Further, each member may have  multiple titles (1:n) mapped in table `title2memb`. Each entry `idRank` has a name which can be found in `title`.

I want to get the first `N` members that have at least once the country "US" in table `country2memb` and I want to display all their titles.

Here is working code, using two `JOIN`S and two `where` statements for `N=2`:

```
<?php

$db= new mysqli("localhost","root","","example");

$sql      ="SELECT DISTINCT m.name, m.id FROM member m
INNER JOIN country2memb c ON m.id = c.idMember AND c.country='US' LIMIT 2";

$result   = $db->query($sql);

while($zeile = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $id = $zeile['id'];     
  echo $zeile['name'].": ";

  $sub_sql = "SELECT t.name FROM title t INNER JOIN title2memb tm ON
  t.id = tm.idRank AND tm.idMember='$id'";
  $sub_result   = $db->query($sub_sql);
  while($rank = $sub_result->fetch_assoc())
  {
    echo $rank['name']." ";
  }

  echo "<br>";
}


?>
```

And as a result I get (I had to use the `DISTINCT` keyword, otherwise I would get Bernd twice):

> Bernd: Bee
>
> Tom: Bear Dog

Is it really necessary to have 2 nested `while` clauses here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Formatting**

Your code has some formatting issues, reducing the readability of it:

- spacing: your spacing around `=` seems arbitrary and you are missing spaces around `.`.
- indentation: 2 spaces aren't really enough, use at least 4.
- you should also indent the queries after a linebreak a bit more to increase readability.
- your curly brackets are not consistent.

**Security**

Depending on who can add members and ranks, you may be vulnerable to XSS as the name is echoed unencoded. Even if this isn't a problem now because only you can add them, your requirements may change. Encoding input is always a good idea.

Also, depending on the type and changability of `id` you may be vulnerable to SQL injection. Always use prepared statements.

**Structure**

You should add functions to increase the maintainability - readability, reusability, changability, etc - of your code.

For example, `selectMembersByCountry($country)` or `selectMemberRanksByID($id)`, which would then return an array of members and/or ranks.

**Naming**

`zeile` isn't a good name. First of all, your variable names shouldn't switch languages, and ideally they should all be in English.

But `row` wouldn't be much better. What is it really? Well, `$result` contains a list of members, right? So its name could reflect that, and then zeile could be member, which would give you: `$member = $membersResult->fetch_assoc()`.

**Simplify SQL**

You could put all the logic directly into the query, but I don't think that that is necessary, so I'll leave that to someone else (although you may want to change your table structure first, see below).

I would say that it's fine the way it is. Especially when you extract the queries to functions, you would have well-defined and reusable functions.

Putting all the logic directly in the query is likely to be less readable and harder to maintain, and I doubt that it will give you a noticeable performance benefit (definitely not if you limit by 2).

**Table Structure**

- Why do your mapping tables have their own id? This doesn't seem necessary.
- For a 1:n relationship, you don't actually need a mapping table.
- member-country doesn't actually seem to be a 1:n relationship, but n:m; A member can have multiple countries, and a country can have multiple members.
- Because of the last point, you actually have duplications in your `country2memb` table (multiple entries of `US` for example). What you should do is have  a `member` table, a `country` table, and a `memberCountry` table to map between them.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Well I guess I need to do some checks how much the performance will improve, when another solution is given. To the 4 Table Structure questions: 1) You are right 2) Yes, you are right 3) You are right! 4) well I tried to simplify my original example which was a mapping between address and member, and a member could have had multiple addresses (1:n) where multiple addresses could have the same country. The way I coded it above was not really good - sorry for that. Thank you for your suggestions.