# Get title from database based on member country

Tags: php, mysqli, join

I asked [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129016/load-title-from-database-based-on-member-country) before. However, I realized that I had to edit some of my code after I got good answers. Therefore, I'm asking a new question here.

---

I have the following database:

[image]

Each member may have multiple addresses (1:n) stored in table `address`. It's possible that one member has multiple addresses within one country.

Further, each member may have  multiple titles (m:n) mapped in table `title2memb`. Each entry `idRank` has a name which can be found in `title`.

I want to get the first *N* members that have at least one address in the country "US"  and I want to display all their titles.

Here is working code, using two `JOIN`S and two `where` statements for `N=2`:

```
<?php

$db       = new mysqli("localhost","root","","example");
$sql      = "SELECT DISTINCT m.name, m.id FROM member m
              INNER JOIN address a ON m.id = a.idMember AND a.country='US' LIMIT 2";
$membersResult   = $db->query($sql);

while($member = $membersResult->fetch_assoc()){
  $id            = $zeile['id'];
 
  echo $zeile['name'] . ": ";

  $sub_sql       = "SELECT t.name FROM title t INNER JOIN title2memb tm ON
                    t.id = tm.idRank AND tm.idMember='$id'";
  $sub_result    = $db->query($sub_sql);
  while($rank = $sub_result->fetch_assoc())
  {
    echo $rank['name'] . " ";
  }

  echo "<br>";
}


?>
```

And as a result I get:

> Bernd: Bee
>
> Tom: Bear Dog

Is it really necessary to have here 2 nested while clauses? Or can I get both in one SQL?

Some remarks:

- I had to use the *DISTINCT* keyword in my first SQL, otherwise I would get Bernd twice.
- I have avoided using prepared statements and encoding the input to make the code more readable. I know that the here presented version is vulnerable to XSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, for questions like this is would be helpful to provide an SQL fiddle. [I mocked one up](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a34c9/13/0) to test on, it only takes a few minutes but would be much faster for you since you have the table definitions.

> Is it really necessary to have here 2 nested while clauses? Or can I get both in one SQL?

You can absolutely get everything you need in one SQL query without nested queries. In fact, you *should*. Performing database queries within a loop is never ideal and it's always a better idea to get the data you need (even if slightly more than you need) then filter it down with PHP to avoid having to do multiple queries.

---

### The logic

> I want to get the first N members that have at least one address in the country "US" and I want to display all their titles.

OK - so you're aiming for two things - the member's name and their titles. Your conditions are based on the `address` table data, so you should start your query there:

```
SELECT `idMember` FROM `address`
WHERE `country` = 'US'
GROUP BY `idMember`
LIMIT 2
```

Your `at least one address in the country "US"` condition is covered by `WHERE country = 'US'`, and the `GROUP BY` will limit your duplicated rows. If you want to see how many addresses each member has (or filter on it) you can add `COUNT(*)` to the select clause to see. You will adjust the `LIMIT` as required.

This gives you the member IDs that you need to retrieve titles for. From here, just query the tables you need and join the results above:

```
SELECT `member`.`id`, `member`.`name`, `title`.`name`
FROM `title`
INNER JOIN `title2memb` ON `title2memb`.`idRank` = `title`.`id`
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT `idMember` FROM `address`
  WHERE `country` = 'US'
  GROUP BY `idMember`
  LIMIT 2
) AS `us_members`
  ON `us_members`.`idMember` = `title2memb`.`idMember`
INNER JOIN `member` ON `member`.`id` = `us_members`.`idMember`;
```

Note that I've added the member's ID here because you'll use it to group the result set with PHP, as MySQL as a relational database is not able to return multi-dimensional results (see NoSQL/MongoDB/DynamoDB etc if you want that!).

> I have avoided using prepared statements and encoding the input to make the code more readable. I know that the here presented version is vulnerable to XSS.

Noted - won't comment on that.

To implement, you can do something like this:

```
$country = 'US';
$limit = 2;

$sql = '
    SELECT `member`.`id`, `member`.`name`, `title`.`name` AS `title_name`
    FROM `title`
    INNER JOIN `title2memb` ON `title2memb`.`idRank` = `title`.`id`
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT `idMember` FROM `address`
      WHERE `country` = "' . $country . '"
      GROUP BY `idMember`
      LIMIT  ' . $limit . '
    ) AS `us_members`
      ON `us_members`.`idMember` = `title2memb`.`idMember`
    INNER JOIN `member` ON `member`.`id` = `us_members`.`idMember`;
';

$membersResult = $db->query($sql);

// Use PHP to group the results by the member ID
$members = array();
while ($member = $membersResult->fetch_assoc()) {
     // Track the member's name and an array of titles against their ID (which is unique)
     if (!array_key_exists($member['id'], $members)) {
        $members[$member['id']] = array(
            'name' => $member['name'],
            'titles' => array()
        );
     }
     // Add the title
     $members[$member['id']]['titles'][] = $member['title_name'];
}
```

This will give you a simple structured array like so:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bernd
            [titles] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Bee
                )
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Tom
            [titles] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Bear
                    [1] => Dog
                )
        )
)
```

Now, loop that array and output the data how you want to:

```
foreach ($members as $memberId => $member) {
    echo sprintf('%s: %s<br>', $member['name'], implode(' ', $member['titles']));
}
```

Example output (from a browser):

```
Bernd: Bee
Tom: Bear Dog
```

---

### General formatting

While we're here, you should consider a few best practices:

- Use single quotes always, unless you require double quotes
- Choose a rule for indentation and stick to it. Four spaces is generally accepted as "the norm" for PHP (see `while` contents)
- Add spaces before and after brackets in control structures (see `while`)
- Space out arguments in function calls (see `$db`)